# Tomcat startup: CLI vs. Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

Hello: I've just gotten involved in a JSP/Servlet project and am starting from the very beginning to set up my Eclipse IDE. I've installed Apache Tomcat (v 9.0.79) on Mac OS 12.67.  I can start Tomcat from the Terminal app just fine using ./bin/startup.sh, as determined by seeing the startup page at localhost:8080 (although the log does show a few issues about a port already being used...could be a Tomcat bug).

The problem I'm having is when I try to set up the Tomcat server in Eclipse (after shutting down Tomcat from the Terminal). I followed all the steps in the documentation to create the server but after I start it the loclhost:8080 address in a browser shows an HTTP 404 status. The console log does not contain any errors.  I'm pointing to the same JRE in Eclipse that shows up in the list of environment varialbles when starting from the CLI (/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home).

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you deploying to Tomcat when it's launched from Eclipse? By default, there's nothing, so a request for `/` **should** give you a 404 error.

Comment: Nothing at the start but I wanted to verify that it's running before I start building a dynamic web project.  I guess I could try adding Hello world to see if you're right about that.

Comment: The 404 error is itself a proof that tomcat is running on port 8080. You would get a "connection refused" error otherwise. There's nothing deployed there so a 404 is expected as @nitind pointed out.

Comment: So I created a HelloWorld Servlet and still get 404 with this URL http://localhost:8080/HeloWorldServlet/  after Run on Server. I'm doing something totally stupid, I guess, but I have to solve this before I can tackle my actual project.

Comment: It's a little hard to deduce why that URL should work--was there a "welcome file" in the project that was deployed as the HelloWorldServlet context? What were you expecting instead?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I've found the solution to my issue with running servlets created in Eclipse, as described above. It's a combination of two things:

1. My own ignorance;
2. A quirk in Eclipse;

More specifically, in the URLs given above I wasn't providing the correct context path.  Everything looked like it was part of a root project.  That's because when I first selected Run On Server that's the URL that was shown and I just copied that.  For example, localhost:8080/HelloWorldServlet instead of the correct path localhost:8080/MyProject/HelloWorldServlet. But even when I figured that out I was still getting 404 because the server could not find the servlet class file.

The second part was figuring out why the class file couldn't be found, and it turned out to be because of the Java build path. In my case the build class path order was wrong: the (new M2P) project path was ahead of the tomcat runtime path so (I think) my class file was never recognized by the tomcat runtime. Switching it to this gave me what I needed:
[image: Java Build Path property for new project M2P.]

It's been a frustrating day but at least it ends on a happy note! Thanks for all the comments. Goodnight World!